# How do I fix an error when running a t-test

Tags: r

In normal r the code for our t test runs well. When trying to Knit in markdown we get an error message.

our code is this

```
f1<-function(i){
        t.test(Joined_cum_strategies[,i])[3]
}
f2<-function(i){
        t.test(Joined_cum_strategies[,i])[1]
}
p_value<-data.frame(unlist(lapply(2:dim(Joined_cum_strategies)[2], f1)))
colnames(p_value) <- c("P_Value")
t_strategies<-data.frame( unlist(lapply(2:dim(Joined_cum_strategies)[2],f2)))
colnames(t_strategies) <- c("t-test")
```

The error message is as follows:

[Error message for t-test in markdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy7As.png)

Comment: can you share `dput(Joined_cum_strategies)`?

Comment: I tried with `Joined_cum_strategies <- iris[c(5, 1:4)]` and I have no error.  You get that error when you are trying to calc a t.test with a constant. If you launch this: `t.test(c(1,1,1,1))` you'll get that error: `Error in t.test.default(c(1, 1, 1, 1)) : data are essentially constant`